# (Semi-)Automatically logging in to websites

Tags: javascript, browser, same-origin-policy, autologin

I want to automatically log in to specific websites, e.g. the groupware webinterface at work. My browser (Chrome on Linux, if that matters) saves passwords for me, but I want a *complete* auto-login, so that I don't even have to click the "login" button anymore.

I have investigated multiple ways to approach this, but none of them has turned out to be satisfying:

#### 1. Use a Tampermonkey JavaScript which clicks the "login" button on the website

I wrote a custom JavaScript which was supposed to just click the "submit" button once I load the login page. Chrome was supposed to fill in the password fields. The idea sounded pretty straight-forward. However, this is bad for 2 reasons: On the one hand, I cannot use Chrome's saved password. Chrome has a policy that the password field already displays the circles, but the password is not actually filled in and is also not accessible from JavaScript *until the user has performed a gesture such as clicking* (see [this Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337429)), which kind of defeats the purpose of my JavaScript. I could go around this by saving the password in localStorage additionally (security wouldn't be compromised, as the saved passwords are not encrypted either), but this doesn't feel good. On the other hand, this breaks a (imho) significant security feature of Chrome. It is the same feature [mentioned above](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337429) which prevents XSS attacks from stealing login passwords. Because whenever I load the login page, the password would be filled in and it would log me in.

So what I would rather want is a special (if possible *local*) page which I can bookmark, but which will (probably) never be known to anyone performing an XSS attack on me.

#### 2. Use a local HTML page which loads the login page, fills out the form and logs me in

This is a simple idea and would accomplish my goal, but of course it doesn't work because of the same-origin policy.

#### 3. Use a script/program

This would theoretically work. I could write a program which downloads the login page, reads the form, submits it and then transfers the cookies (or the login URL, if the form uses `GET` to submit to the browser. However, this would be a major piece of work, especially for the case where the forms use the `POST` method (I'd have to transfer cookies to a possibly running instance of Chrome).

Plus, I'd have to somehow tie this program to a local webserver or turn it into an extension so I could access it from within my browser. After all, opening a shell and typing a command is not really easier than clicking a login button.

#### 4. Use cookies

This is not really an approach, but I mention it here for completeness' sake. By default, Chrome removes all cookies when I exit the browser. I can configure it to keep the cookies of specific websites so I don't have to log in again when I restart it. Some websites use only session cookies, though, so closing the last tab already (correctly) removes the cookies and I have to login again. As a result, cookies only solve my problem for a few websites, but not all.

So my question is: Is there an easier way to accomplish automatic log-in without having to circumvent security features or write a large program?

P.S.: I know, this is a lot of effort to get around clicking a single button every now and then :)

Comment: IIRC Keefox (keepass interface for firefox) has a feature that auto-submits the login form. Chrome might have a similar addon.

Comment: Yes, there are some addons which do this. However, they suffer the same security implications as the Tampermonkey JavaScript. The forms are filled/submitted even if some XSS is loading the login page in an invisible iframe to steal my passwords.

Comment: I think the addon uses the url of the top page, and not of the iframe, to determine whether to fill in the form. Also, many sites use either js code or http headers to prevent their page from being loaded in an iframe.

Comment: [Single sign-on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) may be an option.

Comment: This could be a question for Information Security, but i can also see why it's asked on stackoverflow so i won't flag it. See if the user's on information security can tell a bit more about it

Comment: parchment: There is an extension which uses KeePassHTTP, but the documentation (for KeePassHTTP) is so sparse that it doesnt clear my doubts about having an HTTP server serving my passwords (to possibly everyone). I'll dig deeper into that, though, and report here if I find anything useful.

Hanno Binder: Yes, but the websites would have to support that (and they don't).

SjoerdDeWit: I think it fits here better, because the details are (imho) more related to implementation than to theoretical/conceptual aspects of security.